# How to concatenate columns without null value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This question is asked many time here but i am not getting the proper output as i am expecting:

I have a table in which i need to concatenate columns but i don't want NULL value in it. I want it in sql server 2008 concate function does not work in 2008.

Example:
OrderTable

```
 Customer_Number   order1   order2  order3   order4 
    1               NULL      X       Y       NULL   
    2               NULL      A       B       NULL
    3                V       NULL     H       NULL
```

Now want i want is the data in concatenated manner for order only like this:

```
Customer_Number     Order
  1                 X,Y
  2                 A,B
  3                 V,H
```

This is the code i used

```
 Select Customer_number, ISNULL(NULLIF(order1,' ')+',','')+
 ISNULL(NULLIF(order2,' ')+',','')+ 
 ISNULL(NULLIF(order3,' ')+',','')+
 ISNULL(NULLIF(order4,' ')+',','')
 as Order from Ordertable
```

I got the below output

```
Customer_Number      Order
  1                NULL,X,Y,NULL
  2                NULL,A,B,NULL
  3                V,NULL,H,NULL
```

I already try Coalesce, Stuff, ISNULL, NULLIF but all have same result

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
 Declare @YourTable Table ([Customer_Number] varchar(50),[order1] varchar(50),[order2] varchar(50),[order3] varchar(50),[order4] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,NULL,'X','Y',NULL)
,(2,NULL,'A','B',NULL)
,(3,'V',NULL,'H',NULL)


 Select Customer_Number   
       ,[Order] = IsNull(stuff(
                  IsNull(','+order1,'')
                 +IsNull(','+order2,'')
                 +IsNull(','+order3,'')
                 +IsNull(','+order4,'')
                 ,1,1,''),'')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Customer_Number Order
1               X,Y
2               A,B
3               V,H
```

> **EDIT - IF the "NULL" are strings and NOT NULL Values**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Customer_Number] varchar(50),[order1] varchar(50),[order2] varchar(50),[order3] varchar(50),[order4] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'NULL','X','Y','NULL')
,(2,'NULL','A','B','NULL')
,(3,'V','NULL','H','NULL')


 Select Customer_Number   
       ,[Order] = IsNull(stuff(
                  IsNull(','+nullif(order1,'NULL'),'')
                 +IsNull(','+nullif(order2,'NULL'),'')
                 +IsNull(','+nullif(order3,'NULL'),'')
                 +IsNull(','+nullif(order4,'NULL'),'')
                 ,1,1,''),'')
 From  @YourTable
```

Comment: From the question: *I want it in sql server 2008 concate function does not work in 2008.*

Comment: in case I have value in order4 it will be like X,Y, how to remove last , in this query

Comment: in case I have value in order4 it will be like X,Y, how to remove last , in this query and also if NULL string like NULL, Null, NUll etc then

Comment: @Amitesh Sorry for the late response.  I'm sure you figured this out by now, but If all NULLs, you could wrap the stuff() with IsNull().   For example IsNull(stuff(...),'')

Answer (score 3):

Another variation, for fun and profit, demonstrating the `FOR XML` trick to concatenate values pre-SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT Customer_Number, STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + order1, ',' + order2, ',' + order3, ',' + order4 FOR XML PATH('')), 
    1, 1, ''
)
```

This is slight overkill for a constant number of columns (and not particularly efficient), but an easy to remember pattern for concatenation. Also, it shows off `STUFF`, a function any SQL developer should learn to love.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit unpleasant, it needs to be in a subquery to remove the trailing comma efficiently (though you could use a CTE):

```
SELECT 
    Customer_number, 
    SUBSTRING([Order], 0, LEN([Order])) AS [Order]
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Customer_number,
        COALESCE(order1+',', '') +
        COALESCE(order2+',', '') +
        COALESCE(order3+',', '') +
        COALESCE(order4+',', '') AS [Order]
    FROM
        OrderTable) AS SubQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with the Coalesce, or IsNull.  Instead of trying to track the length and use substring, left or stuff, I just used a replace to remove the trailing comma that would show up from the coalesce.

```
Select Customer_number, 
    Replace(
        Coalesce(Order1 + ',','')+
        Coalesce(Order2 + ',','')+
        Coalesce(Order3 + ',','')+
        Coalesce(Order4 + ',','')
     +',',',,','') --Hack to remove the Last Comma
 as [Order] from Ordertable
```